# Xamarin - iOS MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail results in 'Got a segv while executing native code'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to send an e-mail from a Xamarin Forms app using an iOS code with DependencyInjection which looks like this:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SendMail))]
namespace SampleApp.iOS.PlatformSpecific
{
  public class SendMail : ISendMail
  {
    public void SendMail()
    {
       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
       {
         if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)  <-- crashes here
         {
            // my code
         }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

The line indicated above always crashes on a real device (but works on a simulator). The crash is the following:

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi, I have checked that, and it works. What's the version of Xamarin Froms and iOS device you are testing?

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT - thanks, it's Xamarin.Forms=4.8.0.1451, iPhone 12 Pro, iOS 14.3. I'm trying it with Debug configuration, putting a breakpoint on the line indicated above and when crossing the breakpoint with ⇧⌘I or ⇧⌘O it crashes the mono framework.

Comment: Okey, have a try with xamarin forms (5.0+) to check whehter it works.